# WooCommerce custom payment gateway with eJunkie

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I'm new in WooCommerce code, but successful make custom payment gateway.

On site, I have few packages. When client click on Custom Payment, will see this button

```
<a href='https://www.e-junkie.com/ecom/gb.php?c=cart&ejc=2&cl=ejunkie_client_id&i=ejunkie_item_id&quantity=ejunkie_quantity' onclick='return EJEJC_lc(this);' style='display:inline-block;background: #3da5d9 url(https://www.e-junkie.com/ej/images/newaddtocart.png) center/100px no-repeat;border: none;padding: 7px 55px;border-radius: 3px;box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);text-decoration: none;' target='ej_ejc' class='ec_ejc_thkbx'>&nbsp;</a>
```

After click on the button, need to grab all items and quantity and store in this button. So, need to do it for every package which have on site.

For example on site item id is 10 or 11 or 12 but same item on eJunkie id is 142942 or 143821 or 144912. In button need to be ID from eJunkie.

How can take ID and quantity from order and convert it to eJunkie ID?

```
$ordered_item_on_site = $ejunkie_item_id
$ordered_quantity = $ejunkie_quantity
```